# Geo IP data on stackoverflow API?

Tags: web-applications, networking

Have just looked at [stackgeography](http://www.stackgeography.com/) and at [soapi](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).
I cannot see where the geo data comes from as it's not on the soapi.
Can anybody shed some light on that?
More info on the [stackgeography](https://stackapps.com/questions/2913/stackgeography-a-stack-exchange-question-mapping-site)

Comment: neat little app

Comment: After detailed inspection I can say that the only kind of questions visible on the site is that whose users filled in the location field in the profile. Case closed Columbo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/new) does give you access to user location data. It is [open source](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/), and [Data dumps](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump) of this data are releases to the public.

No one knows how this code works behind the screen but the author. If I had to guess
I would say he using the soapi to get the real time events and marrying that up to user location data from the data dump. If an event occurs for a user that is not in his dump he just ignores it.

[image]

Comment: that was actually my first thought. Apart from the fact that it's ambiguous and unreliable why would he bother with geoapi libraries then?

Comment: I dunno, He may need it to work with google maps..